# Куда лучше разместить Spring Boot приложение?

Tags: java, spring, сервер, deploy

Сразу извиняюсь за крайне глупый вопрос, но все же мне нужно удостовериться в своих знаниях у опытных IT специалистов)

Пишу на Java достаточно давно, практиковался деплоить свои приложения по всяким разным статьям на различные сервера. Но сейчас я со своей командой разрабатываю стартап, который должен работать как часы.

Хочу поинтересоваться у вас на какой сервер стоит выкладывать приложение, чтобы оно хорошо работало. Сейчас тем более из за санкций недоступны многие сервисы для деплоя.

Нагрузка на сервер будет в виде 50 человек в день максимум.

Сисадмины, подскажите пожалуйста куда лучше выложить и с какими характеристиками сервера для моей нагрузки. Я просто в этом не очень силён)

Comment: 50 человек в день должен потянуть вообще любой сервер.

Comment: с такой нагрузкой можно на Raspberry PI, висящей под домашним роутером задеплоить